# How to display Leaflet markers near the 180° meridian?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using Leaflet 1.0.0-rc.2+e02b5c9. I know the default is rendering all markers, polylines ... from longitude -180 to 180 as screen shot here:

[image: Default rendering image]

However, I want to show the map as this longitude I want to show at this point (It is middle sea between Japan and US):

[image: I want to show at this point]

but you see all the markers are not rendered on the right side. Even though, If i set

```
worldCopyJump: true
```

when I drag to the right, all markers are appeared on the right but they are disappeared on the left and vice versa. Actually, I want they are appeared at the same time.

Any ideas to fix that??

Comment: Thank you for editing @ghybs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just make sure that the longitudes of your markers are in the range `0..360` instead of in the range `-180..180`. [See a working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/aWJRginZdn5Mf1Q1sBl2?p=preview).

i.e. instead of

```
L.marker([0,170]).addTo(map);
L.marker([0,-180]).addTo(map);
L.marker([0,-170]).addTo(map);
```

Do something like

```
L.marker([0,170]).addTo(map);
L.marker([0,180]).addTo(map);
L.marker([0,190]).addTo(map);
```

In other words, if a longitude is smaller than zero, add 360 to it. You might want to use `L.Util.wrapNum(lng, [0,360], true)` instead, if you plan to filter all your longitudes at once.

Comment: The link is not valid anymore

Comment: I've provided a new example.

Answer (score 4):

A similar issue has been encountered and reported on the [Leaflet Github](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/1945)

The solution is to increase the longitude of your markers if their initial longitude is below 0.

```
var totalMarkers = markerPositions.length;
for(var i = 0; i<totalMarkers; i++){
    var mData = markerPositions[i];
    if (mData.lon < 0) {
        mData.lon += 360;
    }
    L.marker([mData.lat, mData.lon]).addTo(map);
}
```

Comment: hey @Weedoze this helped me. Jst made slight change in code to if (mData.lon < 0) {
                        mData.lon =parseInt(mData.lon) +360;
                    } +1 :)

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE 2.5 years ago ! Thanks for the "+1". I appreciate

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to leverage the [Leaflet.RepeatedMarkers plugin](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.RepeatedMarkers), which will display a copy of each marker per 360 degrees of longitude:

[image: Leaflet.repeatedmarkers screenshot]

Applying this to markers near the antimeridian works as well, e.g.:

```
var myRepeatingMarkers = L.gridLayer.repeatedMarkers().addTo(map);

L.polyline([[-85,180],[85,180]]).addTo(map);
L.polyline([[-85,-180],[85,-180]]).addTo(map);

myRepeatingMarkers.addMarker(L.marker([0,140]));
myRepeatingMarkers.addMarker(L.marker([0,150]));
myRepeatingMarkers.addMarker(L.marker([0,160]));
myRepeatingMarkers.addMarker(L.marker([0,170]));
myRepeatingMarkers.addMarker(L.marker([0,180]));
myRepeatingMarkers.addMarker(L.marker([0,-170]));
myRepeatingMarkers.addMarker(L.marker([0,-160]));
myRepeatingMarkers.addMarker(L.marker([0,-150]));
myRepeatingMarkers.addMarker(L.marker([0,-140]));
```

will display something like:

[image: Leaflet.repeatedmarkers screenshot, with markers near the antimeridian]
Check out the [live example for using Leaflet.repeatedMarkers with markers near the antimeridian](https://plnkr.co/edit/dXI8BjPCgmnEuFfV46RS?p=preview).

Comment: Any thoughts on how to do this with Angular and importing GeoJSON?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help. Actually, I am not using your suggested codes but I got me the idea to fix it.

This is my solution, hope it helpful for others looking for same solution: 
[Screenshot that was solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL2n1.png)

Always display the icon and its copy on the map (on longitude range you want, in my case, it is from 0 to 360)

```
makeMarkers: (item) ->
  markers = []
  markers.push(item.makeMarker())

  copy_marker = item.makeMarker()
  copy_marker.setLatLng( new L.LatLng(copy_marker._latlng.lat, copy_marker._latlng.lng + 360) )
  markers.push(copy_marker)

  markers
```

In *Item* class:

```
makeMarker: ->
  LeafletIcon = L.Icon.extend(
    options: {
      iconSize:     [25, 25],
      iconAnchor:   [10, 10],
      popupAnchor:  [0, 0]
    },
  )
  icon = new LeafletIcon( {iconUrl: this.iconUrl} )

  marker = L.marker([this.latitude, this.longitude], {icon: icon, zIndexOffset: 10})
  marker.id = this.id

  marker
```

Thank you again.

Comment: I tried to follow your approach however of all the duplicate world map, it only display markers on first world map and the second one on its right. What is the correct way to always have marker repeatedly appear on repeated world map, without the blink effect like with `worldCopyJump` enabled?