# Can't show map markers across dateline

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Seems related to https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2333

I turned on `worldCopyJump: true` to enable continuous panning, but Hawaii has negative longitude and Japan has positive longitude.

Is there something I could do to show all markers in HI/Japan at the same time?

```
Hawaii {lat: "21.277847", lng: "-157.81700790000002"}

Japan {lat: "35.6605134", lng: "139.69903999999997"}
```

*panning slightly between Japan/Hawaii:*

[image: Hawaii with map markers]

[image: Japan with map markers]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820724/open-street-map-is-it-possible-to-change-starting-longitude/38824652#38824652