# How to merge markers placed in two different world map in to one single world map in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, merge, leaflet, maps

I have created a `leaflet` `map` with following code. In this map the markers are placed with their respective latitude and longitude of the ports that are hard coded to hidden field in this example.

Before using `leaflet` we used `google maps`. For some reason we need to switch to `leaflet map`. In `google map` the map nearer to the lat-long which are present in another world map are `merged`. But, in `leaflet map` the `markers` are placed in `different` world map not in `SINGLE World map`.

**Leaflet Map Eg:**
[image]

**Markers render in another world map.**
[image]

**Google map (renders/merge in to single):**
[image]

**Here, in above google map the two world map markers are merged in to one. i.e nearest lat-long as shown below.**

***Is there any way to merge/bring together the markers placed in another world map in leaflet like google map?***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Leaflet Map</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
 <style>
    #map {
        width: 960px;
        height: 500px;
        float: left;
    }


    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
   #map {
        width: 1600px;
        height: 320px;
        margin-top: 2%;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnportsequence" runat="server" Value="1" ClientIDMode="Static" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdndata" runat="server" Value="" ClientIDMode="Static" />      
        <div style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;">         
            <div id="map">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var timer = 3000;
        var array = [];
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("document is loaded..");
            initialize();
            var map = L.map('map', { scrollWheelZoom: true, worldCopyJump: true }).setView([43.64701, -79.39425], 10);
            var positron = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.de/tiles/osmde/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                maxZoom: 7
            }).addTo(map);

            var firefoxIcon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'images/marker-icon.png',
                iconSize: [30, 40], // size of the icon
                popupAnchor: [13, 12],

            });

            var popup = L.popup({
                maxWidth: 200,
                maxHeight: 200,
            });

            var myIcon = L.divIcon({ className: 'my-div-icon' });
            L.marker([50.505, 30.57], { icon: myIcon }).addTo(map);
            var route = L.featureGroup();
            for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                var val = array[j];
                var seq = val.toString().split('|')[0];
                var lat = val.toString().split('|')[1];//.slice(4);
                var long = val.toString().split('|')[2];
                var marker = new L.Marker([lat, long], { icon: firefoxIcon }).addTo(map).bindPopup(seq.toString());//.openPopup();
                route.addLayer(marker);

            }

            map.fitBounds(route.getBounds());
            map.panInsideBounds(route.getBounds());
            map.addLayer(route);

        });

        var mapOptions;
        var map;
        var image_red;
        var image_redLarge;
        var myLatlngCentral;

        var bounds;
        var loc;
        var inc = 0;
        var portcode;
        function CustomOutput(txt) {
            var obj = {};
            var txtArr = txt.split(',');
            $.each(txtArr, function (index, val) {
                var keys = Object.keys(obj);
                if (keys && keys.length > 0) {
                    if (keys.indexOf(val.trim()) > -1) {
                        obj[val.trim()] = obj[val.trim()] + '|' + (index + 1);
                    }
                    else {
                       obj[val.trim()] = index + 1;
                    }
                }
                else {

                    obj[val.trim()] = index + 1;
                }

            });

            var keys = Object.keys(obj);
            var output = "";
            $.each(keys, function (index, val) {
                output += val + ":" + obj[val] + ",";
            });

            return output;
        }

        function initialize() {
            var id = '';
            var datacsv = '';
            id = $("#<%= hdnportsequence.ClientID %>").val();
            datacsv = $("#<%= hdndata.ClientID %>").val();
            var lastitemnumber = datacsv.split(',');
            var input = datacsv;
            var latlongwithseq = CustomOutput(datacsv);
            console.log(" ID: " + id);
            console.log('latlongwithseq :' + latlongwithseq);
            datacsv = latlongwithseq;
            if (datacsv) {
                inc = 0;
                var latlong = datacsv.split(',');              
                $.each(latlong, function (index, value) {
                    var lat = value.split(':')[0].slice(4);
                    var long = value.split(':')[1];
                    var seq = value.split(':')[2];
                    index = index + 1;
                    if (seq) {
                        seq = seq.split('|').join(',');
                    }
                    if (parseFloat(lat) != 0.0 && parseFloat(long) != 0.0) {

                        inc++;
                        var isvalid = false;
                        if (inc == 1) {
                            isvalid = true;
                        }
                        else if (index != latlong.length) {
                            isvalid = true;

                        }

                        if (isvalid) {
                            if (seq != undefined && seq.split(',').length == 1) {
                                seq = parseInt(seq);
                            }
                            sendlatlang(lat, long, seq);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        function sendlatlang(lat, long, index) {                          
            var arrayItem = [];               
            if (index != undefined) {
                arrayItem.push(index.toString() + "|" + lat + "|" + long);
                array.push(arrayItem);
            }
        }       
    </script>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            hdnportsequence.Value = "HNL_PPT_MOZ_BOB_WLG_PTZ_SYD";
            hdndata.Value = "HNL|21.4389123:-158.0000565,PPT|-17.576548:-149.609975,MOZ|-17.5388435:-149.8295234,BOB|-16.5004126:-151.7414904,WLG|-41.2864603:174.776236,PTZ|-41.2905926:174.0010044,SYD|-33.8674869:151.2069902";

        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display Leaflet markers near the 180° meridian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820724/how-to-display-leaflet-markers-near-the-180-meridian)

Comment: hey @IvanSanchez will u please help me to make it working example for given scenario? Help appreciated! I have tried with var long = val.toString().split('|')[2];
                    if (long < 0) {
                        long += 360;
                    } but doesnt work :(

Comment: Make your sample code [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first.

Comment: @IvanSanchez minimal done. i make it work using if (long < 0) {
                        long =parseInt(long)+ 360;
                    } thanks :) +1