# Repeating Markers etc. every 360°

Tags: leaflet

so if you look at the example map on the [Leaflet Frontpage](https://leafletjs.com/) they set a marker in Londons Hyde Park. If you now zoom out all the way the image of the world repeats itself multiple times but the marker is only on one of the images. How do I get the markers, lines etc. to repeat themselves so there is a marker in every Hyde Park not just one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display Leaflet markers near the 180° meridian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820724/how-to-display-leaflet-markers-near-the-180-meridian)

Comment: https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.RepeatedMarkers

Comment: Yes Thank you it does